# Laravel where clause not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using `Where` clause in laravel but it does not seem to be working properly .

Code

```
$login = User::where(
    [
        ['email', '=', Input::get('email')],
        ['password', '=', md5(Input::get('password'))],
    ])->get();

if ($login === null)
{
    $finalResult = array('code' => 100,
                         'msg' => 'Your Account Does not exist.',
                         'data' => array()
    );
}
else
{
    $data = User::where(
        [ 'email'    =>Input::get('email')],
        [ 'password' =>md5(Input::get('password'))]
    )->get();
    $finalResult = array('code' => 100,
                         'msg' => 'Your Account is found.',
                         'data' => $data
    );
}
```

When I provide the email and password, it returns data against the email even when we provide wrong password .

I don't know what I am doing wrong here .

Thank You for your answers

Comment: <groan>When a framework provides strong password handling for you, why are you overriding that and using insecure md5 for your passwords?<groan />

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake i will study it .can you please answer the question also if you can ..

Comment: And your `get()` call will return a __collection__ (potentially an empty collection, but a collection nonetheless), ___not___ a __null__

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `get()` by `first()`.